# ETL Job Issue - Works for One Server and Not for other

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, etl

I have an ETL job which connects to 2 Servers.

Recently it is acting strange with ETL running successfully for 1 server and not for 2 server.

This is with one particular code which has link up to few tables. Runs successfully for one server and not updating for other server.

Please help us to understand what might me gone wrong way.

Here are my observations:

- No Blockings
- No Tasks running parallel .
- It has proper linked server permissions (Read access to all DBs)

Here are the wait type values for OLEDB for server 1 and 2.

**Server 1 :**

[image]

**Server 2:**

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could provide the exact error code seen on server 2. You might need to provide table and index structures involved, as well, depending on the actual error info.